# Extract Paragraph from Word Document Using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache

I have an word document
[Docx file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dgZrOUKHpkrpI15cnhYdVaMK2XuurFHR/view?usp=sharing)

As you can see in the word document there are a number of questions with Bullet Points. Right now I am trying to extract each paragraph from the file using apache POI. Here is my current code

```
    public static String readDocxFile(String fileName) {
    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);

        List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();
        String whole = "";
        for (XWPFParagraph para : paragraphs) {
            System.out.println(para.getText());
            whole += "\n" + para.getText();
        }
        fis.close();
        document.close();
        return whole;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
    }
```

The problem with above method is that it is printing each line instead of paragraphs. Also the bullet points are also gone from extracted `whole` string. The `whole` is returned a plain string.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong. Also please suggest if you have a better idea to solve it.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve as an end result?

Comment: @hovanessyan I am trying to get each paragraph or question as a separate string.So basically I am trying to convert this docx file into an array of string where each string is a paragraph.

Comment: There could be multiple ways to achieve an end result - that's why I am asking what's the desired outcome. You're writing a program to solve a problem, not to have an array full of strings - what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Which version of Apache POI do you refer to in your classpath / project?

Comment: For reference: https://poi.apache.org/changes.html

Comment: What is your definition of paragraph? Are you trying to get each whole question/answer in a separate `String`? Could you edit your question to include an example of the actual outcome and what should instead be the desired outcome?

Comment: Ms word considers \n(Enter) as a paragrph

Comment: @Mars Moon What do you wants to achieve exactly? Add desired output snippet  in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Above code is correct and I ran your code on my system that giving each and every paragraphs , I think problem with writting content on docx file whenever I wrote content in bullet points and uses 'enter' key than that breaks my current bullet points and above code make that breaked-line as  saparate paragraph.

I am writting below code sample may be It's useful for you take a look here I am using Set datastructure for ignoring duplicate questions from docx .

Dependency of apache poi is below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Code Sample :

```
package com;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils;

public class App {

    public static void main(String...strings) throws Exception{
        Set<String> bulletPoints = fileExtractor(); 
        bulletPoints.forEach(point -> {
            System.out.println(point);
        });
    }

    public static Set<String> fileExtractor() throws Exception{
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            Set<String> bulletPoints = new HashSet<>();
            File file = new File("/home/deskuser/Documents/query.docx");
            fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);

            List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();
            paragraphs.forEach(para -> {
                System.out.println(para.getText());
                if(!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(para.getText())){
                    bulletPoints.add(para.getText());
                }
            });
            fis.close();

            return bulletPoints;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("error while extracting file.", e);
        }finally{
            if(!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(fis)){
                fis.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried it but it does the same as my above code. Have you tried testing with the provided file?

Comment: I have tested code for your provided file code is working fine as per apache poi designed but if you wanna saparate each question along with their answer than you have to some  changes in your docs while writting your question and answer than saprate using program while reading.

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find which version of apache POI you are using. If it's the latest version (3.17), the `XWPFParagraph` object used in your code has a `getNumFmt()` method. From the apache poi documentation (https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html) this method will return the string `"bullet"` if the paragraph starts with a bullet. So regarding the second point of your question (what happens to the bullets), you can resolve with something like the following:

```
public class TestPoi {

    private static final String BULLET = "•";

    private static final String NEWLINE = "\n";

    public static void main(String...args) {
        String test = readDocxFile("/home/william/Downloads/anesthesia.docx");
        System.out.println(test);
    }

    public static String readDocxFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);

            List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();
            StringBuilder whole = new StringBuilder();
            for (XWPFParagraph para : paragraphs) {
                if ("bullet".equals(para.getNumFmt())) {
                    whole.append(BULLET);
                }
                whole.append(para.getText());
                whole.append(NEWLINE);
            }
            fis.close();
            document.close();
            return whole.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding your first point, what is the expected output? I ran your code with the provided docx and apart from the missing bullets you mentioned, it looked okay stepping through with the debugger.